# Show cascaded panel (Find and Console) : Sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Sublime displays one panel at a time. Is there a way to cascade the panels on top of each other. For example when displaying the console, if I do `super+f`, the find panel should also display along with the console panel.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible; Sublime only wants to display a single panel at time and so the command that opens a panel implicitly closes any panel that might already be open first (at least logically).

This is part of the original [design philosophy](https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/anatomy-of-a-next-generation-text-editor). As seen in the excerpt below, a desire to maximize space as much as possible is also one of the reasons why the find panel (for example) is a panel and not a Dialog or something else that would take up unnecessary space.

> - Unobtrusive, minimal chrome. The focus should be on the text, not fourteen different toolbars.
> - Don't obscure the text with dialogs.
> - Use the pixels you've got. Full screen, multi monitor and editing files side by side should all be possible.